# Getting ERROR 1054 (42S22) while i am executing the MySQL command in the Terminal

Tags: mysql, shell, mysql-error-1054

I want to collect the data from the `crawlstatus` table where `status='RECEIVED'` and I want to store that data in an file.
When I am trying to do this in the terminal I am getting `ERROR 1054 (42S22)`.

Here is the command that which i used to get the data:

```
sudo sh -c '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --user=root --password=XXXXXXXXXX -e "select count(*) from crawlstatus where status='RECEIVED';" test_navin > size.log'
```

I am getting the following ERROR:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'RECEIVED' in 'where clause'
```

Can anyone help me in solving this problem

Comment: Escape the `'` in your command:

"select count(*) from crawlstatus where status=\'RECEIVED\';" test_navin > size.log'

Comment: What Jens said.  The 2nd ' ends the 1st which begins just after the sh -c.  Escaping it *hides* it from the shell (ish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are passing your query as an argument so wrap query with`'`, but make sure that you add escape sequence to wrap query with`'`

You should use `"` to wrap column value.

```
sudo sh -c '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --user=root --password=XXXXXXXXXX -e "select count(*) from crawlstatus where status=\"802350570V\";" test_navin > size.log'
```