# Call to mysql fails with error

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm making call to mysql procedure and it is failing with the error below. I am unable to figure it out what is the issue.

My shell script snippet is below:

```
export batchsize=$1 
echo $batchsize 
myvar=$(mysql -q mydb -uuser --skip-column-names --execute='call delete_table_incrementally(batchsize)')
```

Code snippet from mysql procedure is below:

```
create procedure delete_table_incrementally(IN batchsize MEDIUMINT(3)) 
modifies sql data 
begin 
DELETE FROM mytable where mycondition='ERROR-5000' order by id limit batchsize; 
commit; 
select count(*) FROM mytable where mycondition='ERROR-5000'; 
end; 
// 
delimiter ; 
call delete_table_incrementally();
```

Error code/response from mysql which executing bash script is:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'batchsize' in 'field list'
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: just check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989967/getting-error-1054-42s22-while-i-am-executing-the-mysql-command-in-the-termina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using your `bash` variable is incorrect, use double-quotes(`"`) to expand variables i.e. something like:

```
mysql -q mydb -uuser --skip-column-names --execute="call delete_table_incrementally($batchsize)"
```

Comment: God damn ! I got it now, apologies I am not well versed with this forum !